# MP3 on Opera - audio error code 4

Tags: html, audio, opera

(sorry for my bad english)
I have a site: http://freetape.webtie.pl/ with mp3 player. It's not working in Opera:

```
document.querySelector('audio').error.code
```

returning code 4 which is propalby MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED. As i know opera supports MP3 so i have no idea why it's not working. Any ideas?

```
document.querySelector('audio').networkState
```

return code 3

Comment: I made simple html site with player: http://freetape.webtie.pl/test still not working on opera

Comment: What version of Opera, and what OS/platform?